# Arduino program is not working without Serial.print(5chars)

Tags: arduino

The following code is working, but I don't want to print anything at all.

```cpp
while(true) {
  String inputString2="";
  while(Serial.available()) {
    char inChar2 = char(Serial.read());
    //on va lire un char et l'enregistrer dans inChar
    inputString2 += inChar2;
    //on va concaténer inChar dans inputString
    Serial.print("12345");
  }
  if (inputString2.indexOf("ok\r\nok\r\n")!=-1) {
    //on vérifie quelle donnée a été lue
    break;
  }
  inputString2="";
}
```

When `Serial.print("12345");` has fewer than 5 characters, the program is not reaching the loop's break.

```cpp
if (inputString2.indexOf("ok\r\nok\r\n")!=-1) {
  //on vérifie quelle donnée a été lue
  break;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific what input are you giving through the Serial Monitor to the program, explain what are your inputs to Serial.read()

Comment: Serial takes input from console where is written "ok\r\nok\r\n". `char inChar2 = char(Serial.read());` in a loop takes input's char one by one.

Comment: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/

Answer (score 0):

`while loop(while(Serial.available()))` is much faster than serial send from other device. So `inputString2` will always be initialized.

Here's a simple edit:

```
String inputString2="";
while(true) {        
  while(Serial.available()) {
    char inChar2 = char(Serial.read());            
    inputString2 += inChar2;        
  }
  if (inputString2.indexOf("ok\r\nok\r\n")!=-1) {
    inputString2=""; //clear variable
    break;
  }  
}
```

But it is not good. How about this?

```
//global variable
String inputString2="";

void loop() {
  //If there is no data to read, exit loop
  if(Serial.available() <= 0)
    return;
  char inChar2 = Serial.read();
  inputString2 += inChar2;
  if (inputString2.indexOf("ok\r\nok\r\n")!=-1) {
    // to do begin 
    // to do end
    inputString2="";
  }  
}
```